# Dynamically wrapping portion of divs with container

Tags: jquery, html

I have basic experience with DOM manipulation and jQuery, but I'm trying to figure out how to insert a new `div` container around the third and last `div`s within an existing container. The number of child `div`s will vary. I imagine I would use the `nth-child` selector, but I haven't gotten much further. I would manually add the new container, but the child `div`s are generated on page load. Thanks!

Existing structure:

```
<div id="primary-cont">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Desired structure:

```
<div id="primary-cont">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div id="secondary-cont">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes nth-child is the correct way to do this if you are using jQuery on the page, here is what i would do:

```
$('#primary-count .child:nth-child(n+4)').wrapAll( "<div id='secondary-cont'></div>" );
```

How does this work?

This will find the **#primary-count** div and then the .child inside of that, it will then childs there after, it will simply do 4 onwards.

However depending on how you are getting the content on the page this might not be the best way to do this, if you're in a php loop, it might be better to use that loop to insert the **div**

For example you could use something along these lines:

```
$count = 1;
foreach( $children as $child ) 
{
    if ($count%4 == 1)
    {  
         echo "<div>";
    }
    echo $kicks->brand;
    if ($count%4 == 0)
    {
        echo "</div>";
    }
    $count++;
}
if ($count%4 != 1) echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks! No PHP involved in my page, but will this still work if there are more or less than six child `div`s? Part of the challenge is that the amount varies.

Comment: It will count up until 6 so if you only have 5 on the page, it will get to the 5th and wrap up until that, i would assume.

Comment: Right. I used six in my example as a possibility, but in the production site, there won't be a limit.

Comment: So you want it to wrap every other 3 elements on the page?

Comment: Not quite. I want it to wrap from the 4th `.child` element down to the last one. So, if there are 10 elements, it should wrap from 4-10, if there are 17, wrap from 4-17, etc.

Comment: Have amended to allow you to wrap from 4 onwards. :)

Comment: Sorry, I just tested this, but instead of adding a single containing `div` to child `div`s 4 and up, it's adding the new `div` to around *each* child `div` 4 and up.

Comment: Update: I've achieved my desired structure using `.wrapAll()`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I built on Andy's answer and used `.wrapAll()` to achieve my desired structure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#primary-cont .child:nth-child(n+4)').wrapAll('<div id="secondary-cont"></div>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can even use `slice()` jQuery method to do this.

```
 $('#primary-cont div.child').slice(3,6).wrapAll("<div class='secondary-count'></div>");
```